# Add a way to only display items that have a Django admin property set to null?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I found that in order to display in Django admin `viewer` application `product` items that have `vendor` set to null, one should visit:

`/admin/viewer/product/?vendor__isnull=True`

However, I am not sure how to enable that from the user interface. I would like to allow users to filter by null value of this field, but creating a [custom Django action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) that returns `HttpResponseRedirect` is not a good option because Django actions require some elements to be selected.

Do I have any other elegant options that would require little or none modifications to Django admin template that would allow me to redirect the user to this specific URL? The two places where I thought this would fit is the navigation bar at the top of the page next to the "search" button or the drop-down menu at the top-right corner where user can log out and change password. Is there an interface where I could inject new options/views there?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this via the URL. You should modify the queryset for the admin so that it returns the objects you want.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     def get_queryset(self):
         qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset()
         if some_condition:  # not sure what it depends on - maybe request.user?
             qs = qs.filter(vendor__isnull=True)
         return qs
```

Comment: The condition is that the user somehow accessed this option, for example by clicking a link. I would like to make both filtered and unfiltered versions available.

Comment: Then why don't you use the [`list_filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) option, which does exactly that?

Comment: You're right! Please post it as an answer and I will upvote and accept it.